# Soma imediata dentro do input - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um sistema de venda, onde o administrador marca os checkbox dos produtos que desejar vender, logo em seguida aparece um input para digitar a quantidade desejada, e ao finalizar a venda, é calculado o valor total de todos os produtos com suas determinadas quantidades. Tudo isso está funcionando perfeitamente.

Porém gostaria de saber se há uma possibilidade de que enquanto o administrador vai selecionando os produtos e digitando suas quantidades, fosse feito um "Cálculo instantâneo" em um input para saber quanto ficará o valor final.

Tentei utilizar um snippet mas não funcionou. Vou colocar apenas a parte do código que me interessa, junto com o script que já utilizo para mostrar e ocultar o input a frente de cada checkbox para não ficar muita informação desnecessária, segue um exemplo:

```css
<style type="text/css">
   input[type="number"] {
      display: none;
   }
</style>
```

```php
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> <input type="number" value="1" min="1" required="" max="10">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> <input type="number" value="1" min="1" required="" max="21">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> <input type="number" value="1" min="1" required="" max="13">
```

```js
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click touchstart', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parent('td').find('input[type="number"]').show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent('td').find('input[type="number"]').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso tem duas condições para atualizar a soma: clicar no checkbox (quando marca/desmarca) ou quando altera o valor (soma caso o checkbox esteja selecionado).

Por isso pensei num evento change, que tanto se aplica so checkbox quanto ao input text:

```js
$('input').change(function () {
   // pega todos os checkbox que estão checked
   var total = 0;
   $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
      // pega o valor do próximo input
      var input = $(this).next("input").val();
      total += Number(input);
   });
   
   $('#total').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> <input type="number" value="1" min="1" required="" max="10"><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> <input type="number" value="1" min="1" required="" max="21"><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> <input type="number" value="1" min="1" required="" max="13"><br />

<span>Total:</span><input type="text" id="total" />
```

Veja que, ao disparar o change, seleciona todos checkbox que estejam "checked" e e soma o valor do input imediatamente ao lado, usando `next` como seletor do `jQuery`

Comment: Esses checkbox estão dentro de uma tabela. Por exemplo, se for 8 produtos, serão 8 checkbox, e como está dentro de uma tabela, eu preciso multiplicar o preço do produto (iria colocar uma $row['preco']]), pela quantidade digitada no input (que pertence à este produto), e depois somar tudo. Mas dessa maneira que você fez, acho que não teria como, pois este script estaria no fim da página certo? e não dentro da tabela. Desculpe não ter falado isso antes, mas eu estava muito confuso na hora de fazer essa pergunta

Comment: *"pois este script estaria no fim da página certo?"* realmente não importa onde vai estar o script, ele só precisa executar depois da página estar carregada, para encontrar os checkbox. Quanto a multiplicar o preço basta pegar o valor, lembre que nesse caso o `$(this).next("input")` pega o próximo input sem nenhuma outra condição, se tiver um input de valor e outro de quantidade, atribua nomes ou classes a eles, pra facilitar e encontrar. Por exemplo se um tivar a classe "qtde" e outro "valor", pode fazer assim `$(this).next("input.qtd")` :)

Comment: Deu certo aqui amigo, abraço!